# Trying extract a geography coordinates from .pdf file with python3

Tags: python-3.x, pdfminer

I am trying to extract a geographic coordinates in UTM format from a .pdf file with python3 in Ubuntu operative system, with the follow code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import textract 
import numpy as np
import re
import os
import pdfminer

def main(_file):
    try:
        text = textract.process(_file, method="pdfminer")
    except textract.exceptions.ShellError as ex:
        print(ex)
        return
    with open("%s.csv" % Path(_file).name[: -len(Path(_file).suffix)], 
"w+") as _file:

# find orders and DNIs

        coords = re.compile(r"\d?\.?\d+\.+\d+\,\d{2}")                                                                                                                                                               
        results = re.findall(coords, text.decode())
        if results:
            _file.write("|".join(results))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _file = "/home/cristian33/python_proj/folder1/buscarco.pdf"
    main(_file)
```

when I run it give me the follow error:

The command `pdf2txt.py /home/cristian33/python_proj/folder1/buscarco.pdf` failed because the executable
`pdf2txt.py` is not installed on your system. Please make
sure the appropriate dependencies are installed before using
textract:

```
http://textract.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html
```

somebody knows why is that error?

thanks

Comment: did you install all packages using   pip install pdf2text  and pip install textract ?

Comment: can you setup python path and then install packages again. Google how to setup python path on  ubuntu

Comment: sorry but pdf2text is the same as pdf2txt?

Comment: finally I could run de script, the problem was that I was installing pip in python2 way, and I should use this way: sudo python3 -m pip install -U pip extract